# Loop through two arrays and match the values

Tags: php, html

I am  trying to loop through two arrays in php and match the answers together from the input html forms

```
foreach ($getMessageName as $eachMessageName){
    echo $eachMessageName . "</br> ";   
    foreach ($getMessage as $eachMessage) {                 
        echo $eachMessage . " </br> ";
        $splitMessage = explode(" ", $eachMessage);
        foreach ($splitMessage as $sM){
            echo $counter . " </br> " ;
            $counter ++;
            //echo $sM . " </br> ";
}}}
```

When the values are echoed through the web browser I get:

```
name 1
message 1
message 2
name 2
message 1
message 2
```

Although it should look more like:

```
name 1
message 1

name 2
message 2
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `array_combine($keys, $values)` you can merge your two arrays into a single associative array, which makes further processing a lot simpler. like so:

```
<?php
        $questions = array ('1+1', '2+2', '3+3');
        $answers = array (2, 4, 6);
        $combined = array_combine($questions, $answers);
        foreach($combined as $question => $answer)
        {
                print "{$question} = {$answer}\n";
        }
?>
```

which has this output:

```
1+1 = 2
2+2 = 4
3+3 = 6
```

This can also be done where the `$values` array is multidimensional.

Answer (score 0):

Prepare a multi dimensional array which holds your output:

```
foreach ($getMessageName as $eachMessageName)
{
    $array[++$counter] = array('name' => $eachMessageName, 'message' => '');

        foreach ($getMessage as $eachMessage) 
        {
                $splitMessage = explode(" ", $eachMessage);
                foreach ($splitMessage as $sM){
                  $array[$counter]['messages'][] = $eachMessage;
                }
        }
 }
```

Then you can print it with one loop

```
foreach ($array as $counter => $line)
{
  echo $counter . ' ' . $line['name'] . ' ' . implode(', ', $line['messages']) . "\n";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You get such result because you just print all the messages for all message names. I think you provided to less information to solve this problem.

Do the array $getMessageName and $getMessage always have the same length and each position from $getMessageName correspond to the same position in $getMessage ($getMessageName[0] -> getMessage[0], etc.)?
If this is the case then answer from pala_ should work (although I think that if you just want to print this data it is too much and it can be easily done without array_combine by simple iteration)

If not then does $getMessage have any information which item belongs to which item from $getMessageName? In such case I think you will have to add some conditions.